# How do I build a matrix using two vectors?

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation, coordinates, euclidean-distance

So I need to build a matrix of `x` and `y` coordinates. I have the `x` stored in one matrix called `vx=0:6000;` and `y` stored in `Vy=repmat(300,1,6000);`.

Values in `x` are `0,1,2,...,5999,6000`.
Values in `y` are `300,300,...,300,300`.

How do I build a "vector" with the `x,y` coordinates above?

It would look like this `[(0,300);(1,300);...;(5999,300);(6000,300)]`.

After I finish doing this, I am going to want to find the distance between another fixed point `x,y` (that I will replicate `6000` times) and the vector above, in order to make a distance graph over time.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use horizontal concatenation with `[]`

```
X = [Vx(:), Vy(:)];
```

If you want to compute the distance between another point and every point in this 2D array, you could do the following:

```
point = [10, 100];
distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, point).^2, 2));
```

If you have R2016b or newer you can simply do

```
distances = sqrt(sum((X - point).^2, 2));
```

Comment: @user3105028 You use `:` exactly as I have it written. That forces `x` and `y` to be column vectors.

Comment: >>  p1 = [Vx(:), Vy(:)]

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: @user3105028 You want the last one you have written but you have 6001 elements in vx and 6000 in vy

Comment: Since R2016b you should be able to get rid of the `bsxfun`

Comment: What would you replace bsxfun with, Adriaan?

Comment: @user3105028 Updated to include what he was referring to

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more elegant alternative (in my opinion) is the following:

```
Vx = (0:1:6000).';
C = [Vx 0*Vx+300];  % Just a trick to avoid the overly verbose `repmat`.

p = [10,100];       % Define some point of reference.
d = pdist2(C,p);    % The default "distance type" is 'euclidian' - which is what you need.
```

This uses the [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) function, introduced in MATLAB 2010a, and requires the **Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox**.